# how to connect servlet program with database(mysql) in eclipse?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.awt.*;



@WebServlet("/JDBCServlet")

public class JDBCServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    public JDBCServlet() {

        super();

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String uname,pwd;

        uname=request.getParameter("t1");

        pwd=request.getParameter("t2");

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/school","t1","t2");

            System.out.println("driver is connected");

            Statement st=con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student");

        out.println("<html><head><title>DATABASE_RESULT</title></head><body>");

out.println("<tr><td>ROLL_NO=</td><td>FIRST_NAME</td><td>LAST_NAME</td><td>"+"CLASS_NAME</td></tr>");

                while(rs.next()){

                    out.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</td></tr>");

                    out.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td></tr>");

                    out.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td></tr>");

                    out.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getInt(4)+"</td></tr>");

                }

                out.println("</body></html>");

        }catch (Exception e){
             System.out.println("exception occured");
            e.printStackTrace();

            }

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }



}
```

and html tag is

Insert title here

```
<form method="get" action="JDBCServlet">

    USER_NAME<input type="text" name="t1" value="" ><br>

    USER_PASSWORD<input type="password" name="t2" value = ""><br>

    <input type="submit" name="login" value="login">

</form>
```

output (exception)->

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at JDBCServlet.doGet(JDBCServlet.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have written separate db program and servlet program both r working but when I written in single program it was not. please answer .

Comment: Define not working. What do you mean by not working?

Comment: i am not getting any output. but  in console as in catch i am getting exception occured. when i wrote before Class.forName() it worked but after it doesnot. thanks

Comment: exception is occuring in Class.forName() method.

Comment: i think the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is due to the missing of mysqlconnector jar file

Comment: then please tell me how to import mysql jar in servlet program ........thanks...@anptk

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what exception you are getting which is very important for anyone to help you.
Assuming the exception is ClassNotFound/NoClassDefFoundError, the 
possibility is that you dont have the mysql-connector jar set in your classpath. If you do it, it might resolve the issue.
Good luck.

Comment: i have entered exception also..............one more thing                            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection   ("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/school","t1","t2");             i replaced t1 and t2  as uname and pwd but still not working.@user3138997

Comment: 1. Make sure you have mysql-connecter.jar in your lib folder. if you dont you can download it from mysql official website.
2. as rightly pointed by singhakash, change Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance() to Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Good luck again

Comment: in eclipse i have added jar file in project and then i removed newInstance() also but it did not work ............thanks.  @user3138997

Comment: To verify whether you are using the right jar, unzip the jar file and check if you see the Driver class. If not download the clean file from  [http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)  by the way when you say added jar file in project, how did you do that?  easiest way will be to place the jar file in to the WEB-INF/lib folder. Refresh and rerun.

Comment: i did it but still it do not work.. now i think i placed mysql jar almost all folders but result steel same..........thanks @user3138997

Answer (score 0):

remove `.newInstance()` from

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()`;

as it is not required and also remember you have `mysql-connecter.jar` in classpath

Comment: no .....i m sorry i did not tell u.....still there is same problem.... @singhakash

Comment: @rajeevranjan how you are adding jar

Comment: **java resource -> src-> configure build path-> (in liberary )add external jar**

Comment: also copy and pasted almost all folders in project...........but did not work.... thanks @singhakash....

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

First the jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" 
contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
pageEncoding="windows-1256"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="LoginServlet">

        Please enter yopur username         
        <input type="text" name="un"/><br>      

        Please enter your password
        <input type="text" name="pw"/>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">            

    </form>
</body>
```

The LoginServlet

```
package examplepackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

 /**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
 public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                   throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

try
{       

 UserBean user = new UserBean();
 user.setUserName(request.getParameter("un"));
 user.setPassword(request.getParameter("pw"));

// user = UserDAO.login(user);
 UserDAO obj=new UserDAO();
 int k=obj.loginCheck(user);
 if(k==1)
 {
     response.sendRedirect("userLogged.jsp"); //logged-in page    

 }
 else
 {

      response.sendRedirect("invalidLogin.jsp"); //error page 
 }

 /*
  if (user.isValid())
  {

      HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);       
      session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user); 
      response.sendRedirect("userLogged.jsp"); //logged-in page             
  }

  else 
      response.sendRedirect("invalidLogin.jsp"); //error page 

*/
 } 


 catch (Throwable theException)         
{
 System.out.println(theException); 
 }
   }
 }
```

And the Bean

```
package examplepackage;

public class UserBean {

private String username;
private String password;
public String getPassword() {
   return password;
}

public void setPassword(String newPassword) {
   password = newPassword;
}


public String getUsername() {
   return username;
        }

public void setUserName(String newUsername) {
   username = newUsername;
        }
}
```

the DAO

```
 public class UserDAO   
 {

Connection con=null;
PreparedStatement ps=null;
ResultSet rs=null;

public UserDAO()
{
    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_sampleservlet","root","root");




    }catch(Exception e)
    {

        System.out.println("Error in connection"+e);
    }
}
    public int loginCheck(UserBean bean)
    {

        String u=bean.getUsername();
        String p=bean.getPassword();
        int flag=0;

        try{
            ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from tbl_login where username=? and password=?");
            ps.setString(1, u);
            ps.setString(2, p);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {

                flag=1;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Error in loginCheck"+e);
        }
        return flag;

    }
  }
```

NB:  MysqlConnector .jar file needed for driver class loading(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)

This is the very simple architecture,This may help you

Answer (score 0):

i made so many mistakes.

1> Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/school","t1","t2");
 in place of "t1" and "t2" there will be uname and pwd.
and also i missed a ':'.
thus the statement will be

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school",uname,pwd);

2> also i didnot import driver correctly
        here I missed to copy mysql.jar and pest it into WebContent/WEB-INF/lib.

thanks friends for your support.........